# Unable to add name and type data to MySQL database

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql

I am new to PHP, I tried editing a source code posted on a website.
I wanted to add 'name' and a radio button 'type' to be inserted into the database with 'phone' and 'password'. But it inserts the data without name and type. What should I do?

**PHP:**

```
<?php
// Include config file
require_once "config.php";

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$name = $phone = $password = $confirm_password = "";
$name_err = $phone_err = $password_err = $confirm_password_err = "";


// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

// Validate phone
if(empty(trim($_POST["phone"]))){
    $phone_err = "Please enter a phone.";
} elseif(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/', trim($_POST["phone"]))){
    $phone_err = "phone can only contain numbers.";
} else{
    // Prepare a select statement
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE phone = ?";
    
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_phone);
        
        // Set parameters
        $param_phone = trim($_POST["phone"]);
        
        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            /* store result */
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
            
            if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){
                $phone_err = "This phone is already registered.";
            } else{
                $phone = trim($_POST["phone"]);
            }
        } else{
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
}



// Validate password
if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
    $password_err = "Please enter a password.";     
} elseif(strlen(trim($_POST["password"])) < 6){
    $password_err = "Password must have atleast 6 characters.";
} else{
    $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
}

// Validate confirm password
if(empty(trim($_POST["confirm_password"]))){
    $confirm_password_err = "Please confirm password.";     
} else{
    $confirm_password = trim($_POST["confirm_password"]);
    if(empty($password_err) && ($password != $confirm_password)){
        $confirm_password_err = "Password did not match.";
    }
}

// Check input errors before inserting in database
if(empty($name_err) && empty($phone_err) && empty($password_err) && empty($confirm_password_err)){
    
    // Prepare an insert statement
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, phone, password, type) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
     
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $name, $param_phone, $param_password, $type);
        
        // Set parameters
        $param_phone = $phone;
        $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        // Creates a password hash
        
        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            // Redirect to login page
            header("location: login.php");
        } 
        else{
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```

Here is the form containing inputs: 'name', 'phone', 'password' and a radio button: 'type'
**HTML**

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($name_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
            <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $name_err; ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Phone</label>
            <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($phone_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>">
            <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $phone_err; ?></span>
        </div>    
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="<?php echo $password; ?>">
            <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Confirm Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="confirm_password" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($confirm_password_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="<?php echo $confirm_password; ?>">
            <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $confirm_password_err; ?></span>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
            <h4 style="color:grey;">How do you define yourself?</h4><br>
            <input class="input3" type="radio" name="type" 
                   value="<?php echo $type; ?>" checked />
            <label class="label" for="control_01">
                <h6>I am a Patient</h6>
            </label>
            <br>
            <input class="input3" type="radio" name="type" 
                   value="<?php echo $type; ?>">
            <label class="label" for="control_02">
                <h6>I am a Doctor</h6>
            </label>
        </div>
        
          <br>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
            <input type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary ml-2" value="Reset">
        </div>
        <p>Already have an account? <a href="login.php">Login here</a>.</p>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Set the value of each radio button to a text instead of `<?php echo $type; ?>` or else it will always return an empty value (since `$type = ''`).
- Tweak your PHP a little bit to something like this

```php
<?php
// Include config file
require_once "config.php";

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$name = $phone = $password = $confirm_password = $type = "";
$name_err = $phone_err = $password_err = $confirm_password_err = $type_err = "";


// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    // Validate name
    if(empty(trim($_POST["name"]))){
        $name_err = "Please enter a name.";     
    } else{
        $name = trim($_POST["name"]);
    }

    // Validate phone
    if(empty(trim($_POST["phone"]))){
        $phone_err = "Please enter a phone.";
    } elseif(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/', trim($_POST["phone"]))){
        $phone_err = "phone can only contain numbers.";
    } else{
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE phone = ?";
        
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_phone);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_phone = trim($_POST["phone"]);
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                /* store result */
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
                
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){
                    $phone_err = "This phone is already registered.";
                } else{
                    $phone = trim($_POST["phone"]);
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }

            // Close statement
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
    }



    // Validate password
    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "Please enter a password.";     
    } elseif(strlen(trim($_POST["password"])) < 6){
        $password_err = "Password must have atleast 6 characters.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }

    // Validate confirm password
    if(empty(trim($_POST["confirm_password"]))){
        $confirm_password_err = "Please confirm password.";     
    } else{
        $confirm_password = trim($_POST["confirm_password"]);
        if(empty($password_err) && ($password != $confirm_password)){
            $confirm_password_err = "Password did not match.";
        }
    }

    // Validate type
    if(empty(trim($_POST["type"]))){
        // $type_err = "Please enter a type.";     
    } else{
        $type = trim($_POST["type"]);
    }

    // Check input errors before inserting in database
    if(empty($name_err) && empty($phone_err) && empty($password_err) && empty($confirm_password_err)){
        
        // Prepare an insert statement
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, phone, password, type) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
         
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $param_name, $param_phone, $param_password, $param_type);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_name = $name;
            $param_phone = $phone;
            $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            $param_type = $type;
            // Creates a password hash
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Redirect to login page
                header("location: login.php");
            } 
            else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }

            // Close statement
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```